# Remove dot from custom defined section title

Tags: sectioning, formatting, fancyhdr

I've just defines a new type of section title following [this page](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-secthead). The used code is shown below:

```
\newcommand{\ssection}[1]{%
  \section[#1]{\centering\Large \\ #1}}
```

If I type `\ssection{This is a test}` I get the following result:

[image]

What I want to do is:

1. (Mandatory) Remove the dot after the section number.
2. (Optional) Make some fancy thing with the number, like put it inside a circle maybe.

Thanks you very much in advance.

EDIT:

I add a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\newcommand{\ssection}[1]{%
  \section[#1]{\centering\Large \\ #1}}
  
  \begin{document}
  \ssection{This is a test}
  \end{document}
```

I've just realized that removing `\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}` the problem is solved, but I need that dot in subsections, subsubsections and so on.

Comment: There is no dot with standard classes. The output is due to code you are withholding. Please post a MWE.

Comment: Added. Thanks you @campa

Comment: Have you considered not defining `\ssection`, but just using `\section` and changing how the titles are formatted using the titlesec package? Your solution would mess up the table of contents and PDF bookmarks if you were using them.

Comment: I didn't know that could was a problem... Thanks for your advice frabjous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this idea to achieve that. But it end up with shifting the star version section heading down as well (As I labeled in figure with red rectangle). You can always add local `titleformat` to avoid it (e.g. add another `titleformat` define before `\tableofcontents`). But this seems to be a little complicated. Maybe somebody have better solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}%
{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%
{\tikz\node[line width=2pt,circle,draw=red,fill=red!20]{\thesection};}%
{0pt}%
{\mbox{}\\}%
{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{This is a test}
\subsection{this is test}
\subsubsection{this is test}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom! This is a goos solution for my case, really. Shifting the star version is a minor consequence that I can dodge.